# How to set up VirtualBox Bridged Network on Windows 7 Host?

Tags: virtualbox

I have virtualbox running on a Windows 2008 server, with a guest running ubuntu 10.04. The ubuntu guest is given a static IP of 192.168.1.4, which also has openssh installed. The guest has bridged network setup, I can ping 192.168.1.4 from any machine in the LAN, the ubuntu guest can also access the LAN. However, when I try to PuTTY into the ubuntu machine, I always get "connection refused". Below are some setup details:

ubuntu IP: 192.168.1.4

hosts.allow

```
sshd : 192.168.1.38
```

hosts.deny

```
ALL : ALL
```

when I the following command, I can see that sshd is listening on port 22:

```
lsof -i tcp:22
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**:

It turned out to be a wrong VirtualBox Bridged Network setup. I give the Ubuntu guest a static IP of 192.168.1.4 (assigned to eth0). Then in the Windows 7 host, in the Network and Sharing Center, there is a new connection named "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" after the bridge is setup, that connection is again given the same static IP of 192.168.1.4. Once I change the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" to automatically obtain an IP address, it's getting a different IP address of 169.254.249.70(Tentative). And now I can SSH into 192.168.1.4 with no problem, even without touching hosts.allow and hosts.deny.

I've also noticed that in the properties windows (see screenshot below) of the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network", the second checkbox, "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver" is unchecked. While the same checkbox of the physical NIC (that is bridged to) is checked. So my further question is: is this how VBox bridged networking supposed to be setup? Any rationale behind this? I'd appreciate if someone could provide some explaination on VBox bridged networking setup on Windows host and I'll accept it as an answer.

[image: VirtualBox Host-Only Network Properties]

Comment: What network config is Vbox using?

Comment: Have you check firewall?

Comment: Is there a firewall / windows firewall on the host machine installed / enabled? I am not sure where in the driver stack the network bridge is settled and whether it completely bypasses the firewalls on the host computer. Can you access the virtual ubuntu machine directly from the host pc?

Comment: for VirtualBox and its network to work properly both vboxdrv vboxnetflt modules must be running. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Also check if you have installed the Guest Additions.

Comment: Vbox is using bridged networking. Ubuntu's firewall by default should be disabled, and mine is the default setup. Win 2008 is also a default setup, and I don't see anything specific blocking port 22. I can't access ubuntu from the host pc either. @Carlos: how do I check if the vbox modules are installed?

Comment: If you made a default installation from Windows it should have been done already and everything should be ok (modules are just needed to be loaded manually in some linux distributions others come with them loaded by default). Check if you have installed the Guest Additions.

Comment: Just installed Guest Addition and reboot the ubuntu, but still get connection refused.

Comment: If you are in a laptop check which adapter you have chosen as default and which you are using in windows. For example, if you are on a desktop without wifi, then you should choose eth0 by default in VBox. If you are on a wireless connection, make sure you have selected wlan0.

Comment: VBox host is on a server with no wifi. VBox guest (ubuntu) can access internet with no problem. I can also ping ubuntu anywhere on LAN, just can't SSH into it.

Comment: I know it may sound like an obvious question but, are you positive to have OpenSSH installed and running?

Comment: Yes, OpenSSH is installed during ubuntu installation. And I can verify it's listening on port 22 by the command "lsof -i tcp:22".

Comment: Thanks everyone! It turned out to be my VBox bridged network setup that's causing the problem. See the EDIT in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar situation and what I did to resolve.  I had my network settings set to NAT, which resulted in my guest not using the hosts network adapter. The ip was set and then I found out later:

Search for:

```
I've installed BigBlueButton using the VM, but I can't access it from a browser
```

On this page:
http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/FAQ

Even though I switched I needed to refresh my guest network adapter to pick up a new ip address, use the commmand ifconfig in the guest to find out what IP its using and set bbb-conf setip to that ip address result from ifconfig.  The guest will use the host's adapter to get out to the web/network.

For a Putty connection, run this command on your guest:
sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Run Putty with the ip from above (ifconfig result) with port 22.

Here is a good read on host-only networking:
http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox