# Pinging problems

Tags: server, windows, netplan, interface, ping

Hi guys so i study for school and i have this weird problem when i can ping from my ubuntu server installed on VBOX to my windows11

but i cant ping from my windows to ubuntu :(

Tried with firewall on and off but results are still this same.

My ubuntu IP is 10.0.0.1
and it perfectly ping PC
(i dont post my pc Ip beacuse of privet reason)

PS: (I Use 1 pc :)

If anyone could help i would be very thankfull
(i have problem with this for 6 hours now)

[Img for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HayJS.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up VirtualBox Bridged Network on Windows 7 Host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102450/how-to-set-up-virtualbox-bridged-network-on-windows-7-host)

Comment: 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0-172.16.255.255, and 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255, these IP ranges are [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (inside your own home/organization/computers virtual network) and non-reachable from outside your network. These are okay to share.

Comment: Pinging between Windows and Linux does not always work. In my office a Windows machine can ping and receive responses from my Linux machine, but the other way around does not work. I can't receive a response from the Windows machine. Make sure they are not reachable by any other means(if this is your problem), not just sending pings.

Comment: Ubuntus gateway on enp0s8 seems to be ubuntus own IP on enp0s3, which becomes unlogical if it's not for internal network in Ubuntu (and there is already an internal network, such as loopback on 127.0.0.0/8). Plus the gateway is unreachable from the enp0s8. They are on completely different subnets. enp0s8 can only reach 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.255 and the gateway is on 10.0.2.15.

Comment: @EmreTalha then what ip should i use for example as a gate and adress if i want have connection to my 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 range?

should i put my gateway i have on my pc?